# sed or Perl one liner + how to replace path in file only when full match

Tags: perl, awk, sed

We want to replace the path on `/etc/fstab` file from

```
/dev/sdb /var/kafka ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

To  ( expected output )

```
/dev/sdb /var/kafka/hadoop_kafka ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

The sed syntax that we are wrote is

```
sed s'/\/var\/kafka/\/var\/kafka\/hadoop_kafka/g' /etc/fstab
```

so once we run then we get in fstab this

```
/dev/sdb /var/kafka/hadoop_kafka ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

But once we run again the sed then we get wrong path in `fstab` as:

```
/dev/sdb /var/kafka/hadoop_kafka/hadoop_kafka ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

So how to replace the path , only in case we match the path:

```
/var/kafka
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following `sed` program.

```
sed -E 's/^([^ ]*\s+)(\/var\/kafka)(\s.*)/\1\2\/hadoop_kafka\3/ Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Firstly using `-E` option of `sed` to enable ERE(extended regex), then using `s` option to perform substitution  here. In substitution part regex using back references concept(to keep matched values in a temp buffer memory, to be used later on in program).

- `^([^ ]*\s+)`: Matching everything from till 1st occurrence of space comes in 1st capturing group.
- `(\/var\/kafka)`: Creating 2nd capturing group which makes sure that it matches `/var/kafka` in it.
- `(\s.*)`: Matching rest of the line here.

While performing substitution adding `\/hadoop_kafka` after 2nd capturing group as per requirement.

***NOTE:*** Above code will print the values on terminal, once you are Happy with results use `-i` option to make a inplace save into Input_file.

Comment: if I do --> sed -i -E 's/^([^ ]*\s+)(\/var\/kafka)(.*)/\1\2\/hadoop_kafka\3/'  /etc/fstab
 , twice , then we get wrong path ( we have rhel linux 7.2 )

Comment: @Judy, I hope you are using `sed`, your comment shows you are using `ed` which is a different tool itself, please confirm once.

Comment: @Judy, ok, could you please do let me know sample line for which you are seeing wrong output? For shown samples it worked fine for me.

Comment: this is what we get when I run the syntax twice --> dev/sdb /var/kafka/hadoop_kafka/hadoop_kafka ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0

Comment: @Judy, ok please try `sed -E 's/^([^ ]*\s+)(\/var\/kafka)(\s.*)/\1\2\/hadoop_kafka\3/ file` once and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: yes this is right syntax -->  sed -i -E 's/^([^ ]*\s+)(\/var\/kafka)(\s.*)/\1\2\/hadoop_kafka\3/'

Comment: @Judy, Updated my answer with latest edit solution, cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The following 'awk' could assist you here

```
$ awk '($2=="/var/kafka"){$2="/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka"}1' file
```

The way awk operates is simple, its syntax, on the other hand, might be a bit unusual for the uninitiated. Awk operates on records, which by default are lines, and each record is spllit in fields. By default these fields are separated by a sequence of one or more blanks (spaces, tabs, ...). Per record, awk will process a sequence of pattern-action pairs written in the form `(pattern){action}`. You can read this very simply is *If `pattern` is true, perform `action`*. The default pattern is `true` and the default action is `print`.

When we look at the above we see the following two pattern-action pairs:

- `($2=="/var/kafka"){$2="/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka"}`. This we can translate as: *If the second field equals "/var/kafka", then replace the second field with "/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka"*
- `1`: This just says one, which equals to "true" and is a pattern, so we add the default action `{print}`. So this statement just prints the current line.

Comment: the target is ti use sed or perl , in awk I need to redirect the output to another file and then copy the file back to fstab

Comment: If you have a recent version of GNU awk, there is the possibility to do `awk -i inplace '(...){...}' file`. Just be aware that inplace is never inplace. It just does the same you describe above, but internally.

Comment: @Judy No, you could use `sponge`: `awk ... file | sponge file`

Comment: @Judy If you have GNU sed or perl for `-i` then you have or can get GNU awk for the equivalent `-i inplace`. Don't compromise the tool/script you use though just for the sake of the syntactic sugar of pseudo-inplace editing. Just look at how simple that awk script is compared to the sed equivalent and notice in particular that you don't need to escape chars or worry about additional regexp metachars or substring matches or backreferences in any of your strings in future as the awk script is simply doing a literal string compare/replace with exactly the field you care about.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `sed`:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's~(^|[[:blank:]])/var/kafka([[:blank:]])~\1/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka\2~g' /etc/fstab
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(^|[[:blank:]])`: Match start or a space or tab in capture group #1
- `/var/kafka`: Match text `/var/kafka`
- `([[:blank:]])`: Match a space or tab in capture group #2
- `\1/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka\2`: In replacement put back value captured in group #1 followed by `/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka` followed by value captured in group #2

Answer (score 1):

```sh
perl -pe's{^\S+\s+/var/kafka\K(?=\s)}{/hadoop_kafka}'
```

How you'd use it:

```sh
perl -i -pe's{^\S+\s+/var/kafka\K(?=\s)}{/hadoop_kafka}' /etc/fstab
```

---

You want to replace the second field, which the is between whitespace after the leading sequence of non-whitespace.

```perl
s{
   ^ ( \S+ \s+ ) /var/kafka ( \s | $ )
}{
   $1 . "/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka" . $2
}ex
```

So, you want

```perl
perl -pe'
   s{
      ^ ( \S+ \s+ ) /var/kafka ( \s | $ )
   }{
      $1 . "/var/kafka/hadoop_kafka" . $2
   }ex
'
```

or the equivalent

```perl
perl -pe's{^\S+\s+/var/kafka\K(?=\s)}{/hadoop_kafka}'
```